# Facesmessage severity

Tags: java, jsf

If I have a FacesMessage Object, how do I find severity. FOr eg: getSeverity()......

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply look in the `FacesContext` instance for the list of messages, then get the severity for a specific message:

```
Iterator<FacesMessage> msgs = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages();
for (FacesMessage msg : msgs) {
    msg.getSeverity();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand where is his problem. He has the object, he has the method name... So what does he need? ;)

Comment: Maybe he randomly guessed and didn't realize to already answer his own question ;)

Answer (score 1):

For those kind of questions, you need to consult the API documentation of the class in question. The one for `FacesMessage` is located [here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html). Now, scan the list of available methods to see for something useable. And see.. Yes, there's a [`getSeverity()` method](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html#getSeverity%28%29)!